# Sql Server 2005 - Time Out in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am using Asp.Net c# and Sql Server 2005. I am using Masterpage and content page. when i debug my code that time it's give error ::

**Window Internet Explorer
    SYS.WEBFORMS.PAGEREQUESTMANAGER TIMEOUTEXCEPTION: THE SERVER REQUEST TIMED OUT.**

Any body please help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an Ajax error - do you only get the error when debugging?  If you want to increase this timeout then set the AsyncPostBackTimeout of your script manager to something large

Answer (score 2):

You have an ajax request that's taking too long to complete.  It would help if you can isolate the request and share what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you sit there too long trying to step through your ajax request.  Either increase the timeout or work faster.

Incidentally, I believe the timeout setting defaults to 90 seconds.  [See this](http://w3ka.blogspot.com/2008/02/ajax-timeout-problem-by-asyncronous.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything *immediately* obvious in that error message to suggest it's a SQL server request that's timing out rather than any other sort of "server request". However, if it is, stick a profiler on your SQL server to see which request is taking a long time - and find out whether it's just a query which needs speeding up, a deadlock, or something like that.

Another possibility is that it's the connection pool - if you're not closing your connections properly, you could be timing out waiting for them to be returned to the pool. If that's the case, you obviously won't see the request in the SQL profiler.

Comment: The OP said that the timeout happens when debugging. To me it sounds more like the typical case of the browser timing out while stepping through server side code.

Comment: @Sergio: Possibly. It's hard to tell on this little information, unfortunately.